# Excel VBA Leading Zeros Based on Data in Previous Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel vba formula that pulls from database connection, fills out data in worksheet. This portion is working great!

What I need however is for one column(E) to be an alphanumeric indicator based on what data is in cell to to left(D). Example; if `D=1-9` then `E=1`, `D=10-99` then `E=01`, `D=100-999` then `E=001`.

I found a piece of code by [Sumit Bansal](http://trumpexcel.com) that seems like it should work.

```
Function AddLeadingZeroes(ref As Range, Length As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Result As String
    Dim StrLen As Integer

    StrLen = Len(ref)

    For i = 1 To Length
        If i <= StrLen Then
            Result = Result & Mid(ref, i, 1)
        Else
            Result = "0" & Result
        End If
    Next i

    AddLeadingZeroes = Result

End Function
```

Here is a portion of datadump into sheet, what I assume is wrong somehow I get type mismatch tried 1 with no quotes too. Something is off;

```
.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = "LockerTag.lwl"
.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "3"
.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = rs("ID")
.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = rs("UnitQty")
.Cells(intRow, 5).Value = AddLeadingZeroes("1", StrLen(CStr(rs("UnitQty"))))
.Cells(intRow, 6).Value = rs("ID")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use formula `=REPT("0", LEN(E1)-1) & 1` or in VBA you just do: `.Cells(intRow, 5).Value = String(Len(rs("UnitQty"))-1, "0") & "1"` (no need for the function)

Comment: Thanks, JNevill. Unfortunately I need it in VBA as I am clearing the sheet frequently based on user data input : (

Comment: Updated my comment with something you can just copy and paste into your existing vba.

Comment: You are awesome JNevill. Works perfect! I was totally overthinking it... Many Thanks!

Comment: No worries. That `String()` function is an oddball. I can't figure out why they didn't name it `REPT()` or `REPEAT()` to match the formula (and any reasonable person's expectations).

Comment: (@JNevill or OP)  What's `rs()`?   Is that a UDF?

Comment: @BruceWayne - most likely that's an ADO recordset object

Comment: Hello Bruce. That is an ADODB recordset object.

Comment: Alternatively you could just add a whack of leading zeros to the front in one step, and then RIGHT("000000000"&"1",2)  equivalent if you needed a say 2 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNevill suggestion worked perfect.

Dumped the function and swapped

```
.Cells(intRow, 5).Value = AddLeadingZeroes("1", StrLen(CStr(rs("UnitQty"))))
```

to

```
.Cells(intRow, 5).Value = String(Len(rs("UnitQty"))-1, "0") & "1"
```

Many thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Log10 of the number (0-9, 10-99 etc.) gives number of leading zeroes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Debug.Print Log10(1)
Debug.Print Log10(10)
Debug.Print Log10(100)
Debug.Print Log10(1000)
End Sub

Private Function Log10(x)
Log10 = Log(x) / Log(10#)
End Function
```

Output:

0

1

2

3